# Use picture as button in einstein bots

Tags: liveagent, einstein, chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I want to setup a question at the end of a chat to get user feedback. I would like to have three buttons that are a picture. Smile, neutral, and disapointed faces. Is there a way to add choices to a question that are pictures? To make sure I am clear, I want to add something to the area of picture 1 that would look like picture 2, except that they should be buttons not a list.
[image]

[image]